# Let me know + wait?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

A friend is learning English and asking my advice about this:

"Let me know [when my brother waits for me]"

Help me figure out how to turn this sentence into proper English, because for me it sounds very strange, but I can't point how to correct it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you will let them know **when** the waiting is occurring, you would use a *present participle* to describe the waiting.

> Let me know when my brother **is waiting** for me.